# How to resolve "Invalid URL http://: Invalid host name" using wget

Tags: web-scraping, wget

I am trying to use wget to download PDFs from a repository. I have a list of URLs saved to a text file that I am feeding to wget.

Example URL in text file:

https://digitalscholarship.unlv.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=3849&context=thesesdissertations

Error returned:

Invalid URL http://: Invalid host name

Example command:

wget -i etd_engineering_list.txt

The goal is download all PDFs located at URLs within the etd_engineering_list.txt file.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple bash script that should do the job.

```sh
#!/bin/bash
input="./etd_engineering_list.txt"
while IFS= read -r line
do
  wget "$line"
done < "$input"
```

based on example here [1](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-howto-read-line-by-line-from-file/)